# Postfix hard bounced emails are not rejected

Tags: postfix, docker

**UPDATE: This problem can be reproduced by installing Postfix within docker container.**

**I tried to recompile from source 2.x and 3.x latest postfix versions, but it didn't solve the problem.**

I have configured Postfix to send and receive emails, but there is an issue with HARD bounced emails - they are not rejected and Postfix repeats sending them every x minutes and user receives "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" multiple times.

In mail.log I see: `[..] delay=5.2, delays=0.11/0.01/0.07/5, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (bounce or trace service failure)`

I added `-v` to bounce, qmgr daemons in master.cf, but still I can't figure out what is wrong.

And here is my config:

```
# postconf -nf:
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 134217728
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = box.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
notify_classes = bounce, delay, resource, software
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_loglevel = 2
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtpd_banner = ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891 inet:127.0.0.1:8893
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_unlisted_recipient,
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/sender-login-maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/dh2048.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = no
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:[127.0.0.1]:10026
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000


# postconf -Mf
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_milters=inet:127.0.0.1:8891
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_tls_ciphers=high
    -o smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers=aNULL,DES,3DES,MD5,DES+MD5,RC4
    -o smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
    -o cleanup_service_name=authclean
authclean  unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
    -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
pickup     unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
    user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu
    user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn
    argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq.
    user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R
    user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}
    ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR
    user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop}
    ${user}
smtp-amavis unix -       -       -       -       2       smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
```

and my mail.log:

```
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/submission/smtpd[22107]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/submission/smtpd[22107]: CCAF8D80222: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=test@fromexample.com
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/cleanup[22109]: CCAF8D80222: replace: header Received: from box.example.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])??(using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128/128 bits))??(No client certificate requested)??by box.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id CCAF8D802 from localhost[127.0.0.1]; from=<test@fromexample.com> to=<nondeliverableemail@toexample.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<box.example.com>: Received: from authenticated-user (unknown [127.0.0.1])??(using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128/128 bits))??(No client certificate requested)??by box.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id CCAF8D80222??for <nondeliverableemail@toexample.com>; Fri, 31 Jul 2015 08:19:49 +0000 (UTC)
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/cleanup[22109]: CCAF8D80222: message-id=<bc058d139ee5208cbc312163e6a0fe58@fromexample.com>
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/qmgr[20607]: CCAF8D80222: from=<test@fromexample.com>, size=646, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: setting up TLS connection to smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:unknown state
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25: depth=0 verify=0 subject=/C=LV/O=EXample/OU=ITC/CN=smtp1.toexample.com
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25: depth=0 verify=0 subject=/C=LV/O=EXample/OU=ITC/CN=smtp1.toexample.com
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25: subject_CN=smtp1.toexample.com, issuer_CN=smtp1.toexample.com, fingerprint=F1:6E:B7:64:96:D3:DB:5C:F6:7D:37:89:BE:5D:E8:74, pkey_fingerprint=A8:F4:72:BA:D8:16:26:11:67:F5:10:4F:96:C3:CF:29
Jul 31 08:19:49 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: Untrusted TLS connection established to smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25: TLSv1 with cipher AES128-SHA (128/128 bits)
Jul 31 08:19:50 b1037ca901c1 postfix/submission/smtpd[22107]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 31 08:19:55 b1037ca901c1 postfix/smtp[22110]: CCAF8D80222: to=<nondeliverableemail@toexample.com>, relay=smtp1.toexample.com[23.75.25.14]:25, delay=5.2, delays=0.08/0/0.07/5, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (bounce or trace service failure)
```

AND here goes bounce emails (one to user, one to postmaster)

```
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/cleanup[22139]: 068B1D80225: message-id=<20150731082005.068B1D80225@box.example.com>
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/bounce[22138]: CCAF8D80222: sender non-delivery notification: 068B1D80225
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/qmgr[20607]: 068B1D80225: from=<>, size=2934, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/cleanup[22139]: 090D2D80226: message-id=<20150731082005.090D2D80226@box.example.com>
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/bounce[22138]: CCAF8D80222: postmaster non-delivery notification: 090D2D80226
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/qmgr[20607]: 090D2D80226: from=<double-bounce@box.example.com>, size=2536, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/qmgr[20607]: CCAF8D80222: status=deferred (bounce failed)
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/lmtp[22140]: 068B1D80225: to=<test@fromexample.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <test@fromexample.com> kdV1ArUvu1V+VgAADqs49A Saved)
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/qmgr[20607]: 068B1D80225: removed
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/lmtp[22141]: 090D2D80226: to=<postmaster@fromexample.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <postmaster@fromexample.com> 4tOQArUvu1V/VgAADqs49A Saved)
Jul 31 08:20:05 b1037ca901c1 postfix/qmgr[20607]: 090D2D80226: removed
```

Here is full verbose log: http://pastebin.com/bsFDsFB9 (editing it  into the question makes the question too long - MadHatter).

Could there be an issue with my config or there is a bug in Postfix 2.11.0?

Comment: I am still investigating this issue, but the issue is with running postfix within docker container. And the issue is also with fresh-installed postfix (no modifications to default configuration files).

Comment: For alternative, consider to post this problem into postfix official mailing list  postfix-users@postfix.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is related to docker + postfix + Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with kernel 3.16 host (I didn't test with 3.13).

Issue can be reproduced without any configuration change if postfix is installed within docker container.

I tried to rebuild postfix from source (2.x and 3.x), but that didn't solve the problem.

To solve the issue I had to install newest kernel version that is available for Ubuntu LTS - 3.19.
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar issue with LXC. In my case, upgrading kernel to the latest available version 3.19.0-39 did not solve it.

I found bug report related to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1446906

Docker uses LXC containers, so that's why this is related. In pure LXC it's can be temporary fixed by turning off apparmor profile with (`lxc.aa_profile = unconfined`). In docker it's possible to pass LXC options with `--lxc-conf` command key.